# Birt: vertical cross Tab page break

Tags: birt, crosstab

I'm using birt report designer for create a report: in my report i have a crossTab with dynamic number of column because i'll do a query on DB with the parameters that the user post. Using the PageBreak property of the column Area in the crossTab i have no problem viewing my report in web browser or exporting this in excel file but when i export my report in PDF some column is cut.

I realize that i view all the column of the cross tab only if i set 'Fit to whole page' exporting the report:

Anyone know how i can manage the export in pdf in different way or if i can set 'Fit to whole page' for default?